# Is there a hard limit to the number of trees able to exist in your town smaller than what is geometrically possible by the rules of tree growth?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Does the game still have a maximum number of trees able to exist in your town?

Are there any ways around a hard limit if it exists by staggering when you grow your trees?

Comment: Well... eventually you'd run out of space.

Comment: @Mkalafut I was considering that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overall limit to the trees.

In Wild World the limit was 24 trees in an acre (16x16 hardcoded areas) and 6 trees in a quarter acre (8x8 hardcoded areas). These limits could be reached for every acre in the game.

In City Folk and subsequently New Leaf, this limit was removed.

Now you just need to adhere to the limit of each individual tree (it's been months since I've played, so I may not remember all of them):
- nothing within 1 tile from the sapling (other trees, buildings, etc...) not counting bushes
- less than 8 trees in a 7x7 grid around the sapling.
- not forming a complete wall with bushes (I don't know the limits of this one).
- Not sure if this is also in New Leaf, but previous games had dead spots where you couldn't plant trees.

Now suffice to say, a perfect town has a limit of 200 trees.